# I can not set a value for ComboBox.SelectedIndex or any other selected

Tags: c#, winforms, combobox

My name's Arnaldo, I'm from Brazil and now I need study C#.

I wanna create a real model or real case to study.

I use the POO, polymorphism and heritage.

I've a "frmBase", that have all I need to a single form, like a DB connection, change size and more.

The next one, that instantiates the "frmBase" is "frmBaseConsulta", this second have a "TabControl" with two guides, one to GridView and other to register information.

And finally, the next one, that instantiates the "frmBaseConsulta" is "frmCadPesCity"; I put in this form a TextBox called "txbCityName" and a ComboBox called "cmbState".

The ComboBox is populated by the table that contains the record of states, as follows:

```
    // This script is in the form "frmCadPesCity"
    public void getStates()                                   // 
    {
        BindingSource dbStates = new BindingSource();

        dbStates = dal.openQuery("Select stateid, " +
                                 "       stateAbbreviation || ' - ' ||statename as statename  "+
                                 "  from country.tbstates  " +
                                 " order by stateAbbreviation");

        cmbState.ValueMember = "stateid";
        cmbState.DisplayMember = "statename";            
        cmbState.DataSource = dbStates;
    }

    // "ChildResources" is an abstract method , declared in "frmBaseConsulta"
    // and override when necessary, like thi, in "frmCadPesCity"
    public override void ChildResources()
    {
        // 
        getStates();
    }
```

In the DataGridView I select a record  ["Sam Diego", "CA"] to correct ("San Diego") and I click in Update button, the guide change to "Register", in the "txbCityName" object receive "Sam Diego", but the "cmbState" stay in te first record "AK".

Follows the script that change SelectedIndex value of the ComboBox :

```
            // Method , declared in "frmBaseConsulta"
            ...
            else if (FocusedElement is ComboBox)
            {
                // Get the value in the table based on the object name
                // getOldEditorValue => "CA - California"
                string sEditorValue = getOldEditorValue(((ComboBox)FocusedElement).Name);
                int iIndexValue = -1;

                // Find IndexValue
                iIndexValue = ((ComboBox)FocusedElement).FindStringExact(sEditorValue);
                ((ComboBox)FocusedElement).SelectedIndex = iIndexValue;
            }
            ...
```

I tried all possible alternatives and does not work , can anyone help me with this?

> SelectedIndex
>   SelectedValue
>   SelectedText
>   SelectedItem

One more thing , when I create a TextBox programmatically to see if it is really picking up the data, the TextBox is created correctly. Follows the code:

```
                TextBox txtComboBoxResult = new TextBox();
                txtComboBoxResult.Text = sEditorValue + " --> " + iIndexValue.ToString();
                pnlCadastro.Controls.Add(txtComboBoxResult);
```

Please, I need a help...

Sorry for my bad English...

Comment: Your problem is not about WPF but WinForms. Now in your code change to ((ComboBox)FocusedElement).SelectedIndex = 2; to see if combobox is accessible or not. Make a figure showing steps what you are trying to do. Figures are best to describe your problem.

Comment: You talk about a `DataGridView`, which is a WinForms control, yet you are also using a `FocusedElement` property, which is specifically WPF.  That's a major issue right there.  If what you want to do is edit a record from a grid in separate controls then why not just bind the same data to both?  Then you don't need any code.

Comment: Thanks all for help me!